# $.ajax(..) and passing custom objects by ref

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, web-services

How to use $.ajax(..) JSON to invoke asmx webmethods that have 'by ref arguments' for custom classes/objects? Is it possible?

My c# code -

```
    public class MyCustomClass{ public int MyProperty; MyCustomClass(){}}

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]    
    public Method1(ref MyCustomClass MyCustomObj)
    { MyCustomObj.MyProperty*=2; return MyCustomObj;}
```

My js/jquery code -

```
function myCustomClass(){this.myProperty;}           
var myCustomObj = new myCustomClass();
myCustomObj.myProperty = 100;

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "{'myCustomObj': " + JSON.stringify(myCustomObj) + "}", 
                url: "test.asmx/Method1",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    var data = response.d;
                    alert(data.MyProperty);
                },
                failure: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

This all works fine if the webmethod's argument is NOT by ref.
With the above mentioned signature of the webmethod, i.e. with a by ref argument, I get a server error (in server response seen using firebub ) -

```
No parameterless constructor defined...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is a scenario which is not supported. You could remove the `ref` keyword and use the argument as return type after having modified its value inside the method.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]    
public MyCustomClass Method1(MyCustomClass MyCustomObj)
{ 
    MyCustomObj.MyProperty *= 2; 
    return MyCustomObj;
}
```

Comment: Thx Darin. I have tried that and it does work as you mentioned. Just hoping that

Comment: @tubelight, what doesn't work? When I tested it worked fine. I was able to get the updated value in `response.d.MyProperty`.

Comment: Thx Darin. I have tried that and it does work as you mentioned. Just hoping that there is something I am missing and if taken care, it will work with a by ref arg.

Comment: @tubelight, sorry I didn't read carefully your first comment :-)